# Vuetify <v-list-item-group> <v-list-group> selected items are not stored

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need some advice. I have two sub-lists. One for Tags and the other for Categories. Each should allow for multiselect. I want to save the selected tags into selectedTags and the selected categories into selectedCategories.

The issue is that selectedTags and selectedCategories are not getting populated.

The second issue is that multiselect is only working for Tags, where there is a v-list-item-group.

I also don't understand why the parent node is only displayed in  - Categories, and not in  - Tags.

Please check code snippet and working Codesandbox [text](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/list-view-p6nrtf) demo.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that selectedTags and selectedCategories are not getting populated.

Not true.  You're just listening to the wrong event.  If you click two tags, you get an alert with one object.  If you click three tags, you get an alert with two objects.  The click event is happening *before* the item is being added, but it's still being added. You can also verify this by putting `selectedTags` and/or `selectedCategories` in their own `<div>` in your template and see them update in real time.

Based on the [API documentation](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item-group/#events), you should use the `@change` event on `v-list-item-group` instead of `@click` on `v-list-item`

> The second issue is that multiselect is only working for Tags, where there is a v-list-item-group.

If you want multiselect to work with Categories, use the **v-list-item-group**, same as you did with Tags. Right now Categories is using **v-list-group** which is not the same thing.

> I also don't understand why the parent node is only displayed in - Categories, and not in - Tags.

Same issue. It's the difference between using **v-list-item-group**, which is for creating a group of selectable items, and **v-list-group**, which is for creating a nested subgroup within another list. You can use both together if you want, it would just require some refactoring of your code.

Comment: Very nice explanation! Thanks. To display the parent node, I will try use example from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#sub-group
I mean two <v-list-item-group> inside of <v-list-group>

I'm also using an input field in the list that shouldn't be selectable, and I'm not sure if there's a way to set it as non-selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the  tag under the  tag works, and expanding and collapsing nodes is functioning correctly.

```
      <v-list
          dense
          class="menu-tree-search"
          style="max-height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll; width: 200px"
        >
          <v-list-group>
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>Tags</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </template>

            <v-list-item-group
              :value="true"
              v-model="selectedTags"
              multiple
              color="indigo"
              active-class="border"
              @change="onTagClick"
            >
              <v-list-item
                active-class="border"
                class="mr-3"
                :ripple="false"
                link
              >
                <v-text-field
                  label="Search Tags"
                  v-model="search"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-list-item>

              <v-list-item
                v-for="tag in filteredTagItems"
                :value="tag"
                :key="tag.id"
                active-class="border"
                class="mr-3"
                :ripple="false"
                link
              >
                <v-list-item-title>
                  {{ tag.text }}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list-group>

          <!-- Categories New-->
          <v-list-group>
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>Categories</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </template>

            <v-list-item-group
              :value="true"
              v-model="selectedCategories"
              multiple
              color="indigo"
              @change="onCategoryClick"
            >
              <v-list-item class="mr-3" :ripple="false" link>
                <v-text-field
                  label="Search Tags"
                  v-model="searchC"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-list-item>

              <v-list-item
                v-for="category in filteredCategoryItems"
                :value="category"
                :key="category.id"
                class="mr-3"
                :ripple="false"
                link
              >
                <v-list-item-title>
                  {{ category.name }}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list-group>
        </v-list>
```

Comment: Please explain your code and why it fits the op's request